# Azure stream analytics timestamp by format

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

When running stream analytics, I get an error message:

> "Dropping events due to improper timestamps. Stream Analytics only
>   supports ISO8601 format for DateTime values"

I have tried the following formats:

```
2017-09-19T13:17:29.0111070Z
2017-09-19T13:17:29.123456
2017-09-19 13:17:29.123456
2017-09-19T13:17:29.123
2017-09-19 13:17:29.123
```

However, when I use the Test button on the query in Stream Analytics, the output comes out fine. Also, when I comment out the timestamp by clause, the query works, but the System.timestamp in the select statment will not return the correct time.

Is this a formatting issue or something else?

Comment: Can you try explicitly converting timestamp by expression to a datetime and use that? It can be done using cast

Comment: That might have helped some, the error no longer comes up, but there is no output (into a blob as csv) when the stream is running.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, as Vignesh Chandramohan mentioned, you can try to use [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn834995.aspx) to convert the expression to DateTime, and check if it returns data conversion error that indicates any input data/value cannot cast to type 'datetime'.

Secondly, many factors can cause no output issue, for example: A where clause in the query filtered out their events that prevented outputs from being generated; Timestamp for events is before the job start time and therefore events are being dropped etc.

For detailed steps to debug with Azure Stream Analytics jobs, please check the **Diagnose and solve problems** on Azure portal or [this article: Troubleshooting guide for Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-troubleshooting-guide).

[image]

Comment: I have tried three things, restarting the stream analytics job at the same moment. When I don't cast and use the "timestamp by", I get the error with no output. When I comment out the "timestamp by", I get output with no error. When I do cast and use "timestamp by", I get no error but no output. Also, in all three of those scenarios, when I use the "test" button on the input, it shows results for all three cases.

Comment: If you still can not find the cause of issue after you tried all troubleshooting steps, you can try to [create a support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and get help from Azure support engineer.

Comment: Hi, one question: does the start time of the job earlier than the events coming from your data source? You can specify the time when you start the job (and can start a job in the past). If the events times are prior to your start time they won't be processed.